# Search for a file in the entire system

Tags: windows-10

I might be doing something stupid, but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to run a file search inside my entire system. I already posted this question on stack exchange, only to be pointed out this is the right place for it :P #st00pid

## Current behavior

If I open a `File Explorer` window, then go to `This PC` and enter a search term inside the `Search this PC` field, the search does not appear to run.

I have already enabled enhanced search and removed all the excluded folders for good measure.

#### EDIT:

I also noticed that as long as the `search this pc` field is in focus (blinking cursor), the search query results are listed as a drop down underneath the search field, but when I press `enter` the results disappear from the drop down and they are not shown in the File Explorer window. See image.

[Results are appearing, but only as a drop down underneath the search field.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0b4ya.jpg)

So it does look like the search **is** running, but I cannot get the results as a list inside `Explorer`.

Rebooting doesn't fix the problem. Nor changing the search query by adding wildcards.

Using the search function from the task bar yields no result and directs me to File Explorer.

My girlfriend's account on the same machine works as expected, so it has to be something with my user account.

## Expected behavior

The search results should be returned when I press `Enter`, as they do if running the search in a single drive.

## Workaround

I can run the search for each separate drive. But I have four of them, so I'd rather run the search system-wide.

## Windows version

Windows 10 Pro 1909 18363.1016

---

Thanks

Comment: does this help? https://www.howtogeek.com/424526/how-to-search-all-your-pcs-files-in-windows-10s-start-menu/

Comment: When you type in a term, does the main window say "Working on it" and does the address bar show a green progress bar?

Comment: From a PowerShell prompt, you could always try `dir -Recurse -path "C:\" -filter "filetofind.doc" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -file`

Comment: I edited my question and added some more details.

Comment: @HelpingHand The search from the prompt does seem to work, I'll keep that in mind!

Answer (score 0):

This should work without a problem. I do this often with success. What I always do, is to think of the phrase I want to find and putt it into stars: `*searchterm*`

Also, did you press enter? Recently Microsoft changed a thing, where the search is not running automatically (at least for me).

Did you reboot your PC? It might be also a bug because of a windows update - maybe one, that needs a reboot. This can sometimes fix such bugs. It definitely should work.

It sucks, but can help with such problems.

You sure could write a batch script for that purpouse, but I doubt, it is worth the extra effort.

I tested it myself just now. I have C:\ and K:.
Both have a downloads folder. It found allsorts of entries on both drives and the mentioned downloads folder.

Please test it with `*searchterm*`. The * is a placeholder which means any sort of symbols can be located before and after the search term.

I did this with the latest update installed and a reboot to finish today, for reference.

If this does not work, please give us more details.

- Version of Windows
- Exact 1:1 search term used. (You can use the code function, to make sure no special sign is used to format the text like the star *)

Comment: The wildcards don't seem to be the problem. See edited question for more information. Thanks!